# Express - Sequelize - Adding Foreign Table Field in Query

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am able to make queries to my `images` table and correctly pull my records, but I'm looking to modify my query to include the `body` field from my foreign table that is connected to my primary table via the `description_id`. I have created the relationship within my database, but wasn't sure if changes were needed to my sequelize model code or if a simple change to my query will achieve what I'm looking for.

Here is my query:

```
router.get('/:pattern/:color/result', function(req, res, image){

    console.log(req.params.color);
    console.log(req.params.pattern);

    Images.findAll({ 
        where: {
            pattern: req.params.pattern,
            color: req.params.color
        },
        attributes: ['id', 'pattern', 'color', 'imageUrl', 'imageSource', 'description_id']
    }).then(function(image){
        console.log(image.description_id);
        //console.log(doc.descriptions_id);
        res.render('pages/result.hbs', {
            pattern : req.params.pattern,
            color : req.params.color,
            image : image
            })
        });
});
```

Here is my `images` model:

```
var Sequelize      = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize('db', 'admin', 'pwd', {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    dialect: 'mysql'
});


var Images = sequelize.define('images', {
    pattern: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        field: 'pattern'
    },
    color: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        field: 'color'
    },
    imageUrl: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        field: 'imageUrl'
    },
    imageSource: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        field: 'imageSource'
    },
    description_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        field: 'description_id'
    }
});

module.exports = Images;
```

`description` model:

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize('db', 'admin', 'pwd', {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    dialect: 'mysql'
});

var Description = sequelize.define('description', {
    color: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        field: 'color'
    },
    body: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        field: 'body'
    }
});

module.exports = Description;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create some associations for your models (see the [docs for defining associations](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/associations/)).  Then, in your query, you'll need to add the `include` option (see the [docs about querying associations](http://sequelize.readthedocs.org/en/latest/docs/querying/#relations-associations)).

Answer (score 0):

You should use [associations](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/)

e.g. one-to-one association

```
var Images = sequelize.define('images', {
    //properties..
    description_id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        field: 'description_id'
    }
},{
  classMethods: {
    associate: function(models) {
      Image.belongsTo(models.Description, {foreignKey: 'description_id'});
    }
});
```

now you can get description by getter [Image#getDescription()](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/associations/belongs-to/).

```
 var Description = require('description.js') //require description model
 Images.findAll({ 
            where: {
                pattern: req.params.pattern,
                color: req.params.color
            },
            include: [ Description ], /*make join with associated model's table*/
            attributes: ['id', 'pattern', 'color', 'imageUrl', 'imageSource', 'description_id']
  }).then(function(image){
     console.log(image.getDescription());
     //console.log(doc.descriptions_id);
     res.render('pages/result.hbs', {
       pattern : req.params.pattern,
       color : req.params.color,
       image : image
     })
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I made your suggested changes and I received this error despite check my database table and seeing the foreign key being set. `Unhandled rejection Error: description is not associated to images!
    at validateIncludedElement (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/node/assistant/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:567:11)` Any thoughts on why it wouldn't be recognized? Here is the line from my table that shows the foreign key `KEY `description_id` (`description_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `images_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`description_id`) REFERENCES `description` (`description_id`)
`

Comment: @DJStroky so you are saying add `Description.hasMany(Images, {as: 'images'});
` to my `description` model?

Comment: @DJStroky still have the same error message. Is there anything else that I should add to the `include: [ Description ]` section of my query?